# Django Python unique=True Expression

Tags: python, django

I want to save Entries in my database such that I can delete them later. To identify them, i put the `key` attribute in my class `Entry` in `models.py` as shown below:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    key = models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
```

Every time I start the server, I will find the biggest key that is in `Entry.objects.all()`.

Every time I create the first new `Entry` after starting the server, I want to take the `key` I found in the very beginning, increase it by 1 and then set this as the `key` for my new `Entry`. For every subsequent `Entry`, I will just take the `key` of the previous element, increase it by 1 and. set it as the `key` for my new `Entry`

However, before I do this, I want to know what Django considers as unique. For example, if i added three entries initially with keys `1`, `2` and `3`, and then I delete the last element with key `3`. If I then restart the server, the biggest `key` I will find is `2` and the next `Entry` I will add will have `key` 2+1 which is equal to `3` again.

Is this `key` unique? 
It was entered before but I deleted that element right? So is uniqueness determined by whatever I entered in the past or just depending on the elements currently in the database?

Also, does Django keep a track of all the instances of `Entry` that I added, so that it would somehow know if I added an `Entry` with `key` `3` before?

Note that my data is stored in a file called `db.sqlite3`

Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to use some autoincrement feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this has anything to do with Django at all. This is pure database stuff: unique constraints are handled exclusively by the database, in your case SQLite, although the functionality is exactly the same for other DBs as well.

Of course, a unique constraint only takes into account rows that actually exist: what would be the point otherwise?

There are other things to bear in mind with your proposal as well. In particular, there is the issue of race conditions: if you do a query to get the maximum key value, and then create a new row with key+1, you run the risk of another user in the meantime adding their own row at key+1. Much better, as Iris and ryanageles suggest, to use the built-in primary key which is already automatically defined as the `id` field.

Comment: I get it. I only have one user for now since this is for a project. I'll try and just go with id.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for something that already exists; models have an id field by default which is unique and monotonic (newer entries have bigger id).

Comment: I could use that but the way my template was structured, I couldn't pass in the ID of the image I was deleting. I'll restructure it maybe.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `primary_key=True` in your key field.

Comment: What will this do? And do you know anything about the other stuff I asked?